# Can we downvote for close reasons? Vice versa?

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-close

I was somewhat annoyed that [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41184/is-there-a-difference-between-not-having-being-and-nothingness) question seems to have gotten a downvote for reasons which are included in the close option. specifically, for being too broad.

Are those sorts of downvotes suitable? What about vice verse, e.g. voting to close because the question isnt helpful (which seems to be a little absurd)?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), users with sufficient reputation may downvote posts "whenever [they] encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." Basically, when you have reached a certain reputation (125) you are trusted to know the site well enough to judge yourself what deserves a downvote.